# Group every two documents in MongoDB aggregate/mapReduce query

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I need to sum certain values from every two documents from a list of sorted documents in MongoDB. I would like to achieve something like this in `pandas`:

```
df['next_datetime'] = df['start_datetime'].shift(-1)
df['timelapse'] = (df['next_datetime'] - df['start_datetime'])
```

My data structure is something like:

```
{_id: 1,
 start_datetime: ISODate(),
 user: a,
 action: X
}
{_id: 2,
 start_datetime: ISODate(),
 user: a,
 action: Y
}
```

And my query so far:

```
res = db.user_db.usage_log.aggregate([
    {'$match' : {'user': {'$in': user_list}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'user': 1, 'start_datetime': 1}},
    {"$sort": sort_dict}
])
```

Do you know if this is possible in MongoDB?

Comment: did you figure it out?